# C# Razor Pages sending checkbox values in AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a model class as such:

```
public class DataModel
{   
    public bool Display { get; set; }
}
```

I am posting the value from a checkbox after deserializing a FormData object to a JSON object, like this:

```
this.FormToJSON = form => {
    const json = {};

    new FormData(form).forEach((value, key) => {
      // Ignore the Anti-Forgery Token
      if (key !== "__RequestVerificationToken") {
        json[key] = value;
      }
    });

    return json;
}
```

The handler over at the page looks like this:

```
public IActionResult OnPostSave([FromBody] DataModel model)
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

The Display property is bound to an input of type checkbox, so when its value of "true" is trying to be deserialized at the Page Handler, this obviously fails and my model parameter ends up being null.

The fix for this *would* be simple, instead of:

```
json[key] = value;
```

I could just write

```
json[key] = JSON.parse(value);
```

The only problem is, if I submit a text field that has a value of "true", it gets converted to a boolean, which is obviously not what I want.

Is there a good/better way of doing this? I want to be able to do all my calls in AJAX, because I want to handle the response on the front end i.e if it failed, show a dialog etc. (do not want to use jquery)

Comment: I am not very clear about what you want. Do you want to submit a form to the backend ?

Comment: Yep, ultimately im trying to get the form data over to the backend. Because it's in the request body, I'm converting the form into a javascript object, which is then serialized and sent over. But as mentioned, booleans that are bound to a checkbox have a value of "true" and not true, so it won't bind back when sending my request

Comment: Note you need to keep the property name in the form are the same with your property  in DataModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work!

I'm now converting the form into a request like so

```
fetch(pageHandlerURL, {
  method: "POST",
  body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(formElement))
}).then(response => {
  // handle response
});
```

And on my page handler, it's been slightly changed to this

```
public IActionResult OnPostSave([FromForm] DataModel model)
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> C# Razor Pages sending checkbox values in AJAX

Do you want to use `data: $('#idForm').serialize(),`   ?

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<form id="idForm"> 
 <input asp-for="Display"  />
         
 <input type="submit" value="submit" id="sub" />
</form>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        // this is the id of the form
        $("#idForm").submit(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

           
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/checkboxvalue?handler=Save",
                data: $('#idForm').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
               
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success"); // show response 
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });

        });
        });
</script>
```

And remove `[FromBody]`

```
public IActionResult OnPostSave(DataModel model)
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

To add below in the pagemodel:

```
 public bool Display { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is great! In my scenario though, I've built a generic method that takes a form and submits it, so I don't actually know what the values are, so I can't declare the variables and send them like this. Is there a way in vanilla JS to do what you're doing but using any given form?

Comment: @Jack Hickey  Do you want  to use `$('#idForm').serialize()` ?  Please see my update.

Comment: I'm not using JQuery, but it looks like that just formats it into a URL-encoded string, is it possible to use that in a request body to the page handler?